# List de Objeto Custom, dentro de List de Nombre

Tags: c#, lista

no estoy seguro si el titulo de la pregunta sea el correcto..

*Necesito una Lista de Objetos Customs, que dentro tiene otro objeto Custom, este ultimo objeto tiene varias propiedades. Al problema*

Necesito leer un Excel, que tiene muchos Libros, cada Libro tiene muchos Registros. Eso ya lo hago pero lo necesito todo en un solo objeto.

Actualmente obtengo los nombres de la siguiente manera.

```
var worksheetNames = excelSheet.GetWorksheetNames().ToList();
```

Esto me devuelve una List de string con los nombres, luego con un for a esta lista, obtengo los valores de cada libro.

```
for (int z = 0; z < worksheetNames.Count; z++)
{
   List<RegistrosExcel> Resultado = new List<RegistrosExcel>();
   Resultado = excel.ToEntidadHojaExcelList(fichero, worksheetNames[z]);
}
```

Y proceso...

Lo que deseo tener, es un solo objeto con todos los valores de todos los libros dentro. Algo asi:

```
//Asi es como lo necesito pero no lo consigo
MiObjeto.Nombres = excelSheet.GetWorksheetNames().ToList();
for (int z = 0; z < MiObjeto.Nombres.Count; z++)
{
    MiObjeto[z].Registros = excel.ToEntidadHojaExcelList(fichero, MiObjeto[z]);
}
```

De esta manera me resultara mas facil leer los datos, al final quiero tener un control asi.

```
MiObjeto[z].Registros[i].Algo
MiObjeto.[Nombre Del Libro].Regitros[No Registro].Total
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), que es como una propiedad para acceder a los datos de una clase con una clave usualmente un numero o una cadena:

```
public class MiObjeto 
{
    Dictionary<String, List<RegistrosExcel>> registros;

    public MiObjeto() {
        // Inicializa el diccionario
        registros = new Dictionary<String, List<RegistrosExcel>>();
        // obtiene los nombres
        var worksheetNames = excelSheet.GetWorksheetNames().ToList();
        // Itera los nombres y agrega una lista para cada nombre
        for (int z = 0; z < worksheetNames.Count; z++)
        {
           List<RegistrosExcel> resultado = excel.ToEntidadHojaExcelList(fichero, worksheetNames[z]);
           registros.Add(worksheetNames[z], resultado);
        }
    }

    // Indexer
    public List<RegistrosExcel> this[string libro]
    {
        get
        {
            // devuelve la lista si existe, si no devuelve una vacia
            return registros.ContainsKey(libro) ? registros[libro] : Enumerable.Empty<RegistrosExcel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Internamente la clase guarda los datos en un diccionario que relaciona cada nombre de libro con una lista de registros:

```
// Puedes usar la clase de la siguiente forma
MiObjeto miobjecto = new MiObjeto();
miobjecto[nombreLibro][noRegistro].Total;
```

Comment: Gracias, hasta ahora crea el objeto como comentas, MiObjeto[nombrelibro][Registros], vere como recorrerlo por nombre y posteriormente por registro, pero es gran avance.